# bash - Extract part of string

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I have a string something like this

```
xsd:import schemaLocation="AppointmentManagementService.xsd6.xsd" namespace=
```

I want to extract the following from it :

```
AppointmentManagementService.xsd6.xsd
```

I have tried using regex, bash and sed with no success. Can someone please help me out with this?

The regex that I used was this :

```
/AppointmentManagementService.xsd\d{1,2}.xsd/g
```

Answer (score 2):

Your string is:

```
nampt@nampt-desktop:$ cat 1
xsd:import schemaLocation="AppointmentManagementService.xsd6.xsd" namespace=
```

Try with awk:

```
cat 1 | awk -F "\"" '{print $2}'
```

Output:

```
AppointmentManagementService.xsd6.xsd
```

Answer (score 1):

`sed` doesn't recognize `\d`, use `[0-9]` or `[[:digit:]]` instead:

```
sed 's/^.*schemaLocation="\([^"]\+[[:digit:]]\{1,2\}\.xsd\)".*$/\1/g'
## or
sed 's/^.*schemaLocation="\([^"]\+[0-9]\{1,2\}\.xsd\)".*$/\1/g'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use bash native regex matching:

```
$ in='xsd:import schemaLocation="AppointmentManagementService.xsd6.xsd" namespace='

$ if [[ $in =~ \"(.+)\" ]]; then echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"; fi
```

Output:

> AppointmentManagementService.xsd6.xsd

Based on your example, if you want to grant, at least, 1 or, at most, 2 digits in the `.xsd...` component, you can fine tune the regex with:

```
$ if [[ $in =~ \"(AppointmentManagementService.xsd[0-9]{1,2}.xsd)\" ]]; then echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"; fi
```

Answer (score 1):

using PCRE in *GNU* `grep`

```
grep -oP 'schemaLocation="\K.*?(?=")'
```

this will output pattern matched between `schemaLocation="` and very next occurrence of `"`

Reference:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/13472/109046

Answer (score 1):

Also we can use 'cut' command for this purpose,

`[root@code]# echo "xsd:import schemaLocation=\"AppointmentManagementService.xsd6.xsd\" namespace=" | cut -d\" -f 2
AppointmentManagementService.xsd6.xsd`

Answer (score 0):

```
s='xsd:import schemaLocation="AppointmentManagementService.xsd6.xsd" namespace='
echo $s | sed 's/.*schemaLocation="\(.*\)" namespace=.*/\1/'
```

Comment: Although this answer might possibly be correct, I'm recommending deletion as it has no explanation.